# Identify three increasing adjacent numbers in Java program. Gives wrong output and an indexoutofbound exception error

Tags: java

What i'm trying to do: A Java program that accepts five integers from the user as input. Program should print "true"if the array contains, somewhere, three increasing adjacent numbers like ...4,5,6 otherwise print
"false".

```
import java.util.*;
class Five
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int [] anArray;
        anArray = new int[5];
        for(int i =0; i<5;i++)
        {
            Scanner s  = new Scanner (System.in);
            int num = s.nextInt();
            anArray[i] = num;
        }
        int flag = 0;
        int count = 1;

        for(int j= 0; j< 5;j++)
        {
            int diff = (anArray[j + 1] - anArray[j]);
            if (diff == 1  )
            {  
                if (flag == 1)
                {
                    count = 1;
                    flag = 0;
                }
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
            if (count == 3)
            {
                System.out.println("true"); 
            }  
            else
            {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
     }

}
```

Comment: `anArray[j + 1]` will give an index out of bounds error when j == 4.

Comment: What should i use instead of j +1 then?

Comment: j+1 is fine, but you need to iterate j < 4, not j < 5.

Answer (score 1):

You always check one element ahead (i+1) so you'll want to stop one element before you usually do.
First you check whether the next element is greater than the current, if it is, increase the count.
If it isn't, reset the count, unless you've already reached 3 consecutive increasing numbers, in which case you're done.

Try;

```
for(int i = 0; i < anArray.length-1; i++)
{
   if(anArray[i+1] > anArray[i])
   {
      count++;
   }
   else if(count == 3) break;
   else count = 0;
}

if(count == 3) System.out.println("true"); 
else System.out.println("false");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Scanner out of loop, you don't need to create it every time to read
        // final because you need just one and don't want to change it

        int[] anArray = new int[5];
        // array created inline
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            anArray[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < anArray.length - 1; j++) {
            if (anArray[j] + 1 == anArray[j+1]) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }

            if (count == 3) {
                System.out.println("true");
            } else {
                System.out.println("false");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also write your program in a little shorter form:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Five {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] anArray = new int[5];
```

This had been two separate lines in your code.

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This should not be inside the for loop, since you don’t need a new scanner each time. You can create it once and then re-use it.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
```

I replaced the 5 here, so if you later want to check a larger array, you just have to replace the 5 in one location.

```
      anArray[i] = s.nextInt();
```

I removed the extra variable here. The expressions on both sides of the = can be as complicated as you want.

```
    }

    boolean containsThreeAdjacentNumbers = false;
    for (int j = 0; j + 2 < anArray.length; j++) {
```

I changed the condition here. We are looking for three adjacent numbers, they are at the indexes `j`, `j + 1` and `j + 2`, therefore the highest array index is `j + 2`. This must be smaller than the length of the array, so this is exactly what the condition checks.

```
      if (anArray[j] + 1 == anArray[j + 1] && anArray[j + 2] == anArray[j + 2]) {
        containsThreeAdjacentNumbers = true;
      }
    }

    System.out.println(containsThreeAdjacentNumbers);
```

The `println` method already knows how to print anything (including `boolean` variables), so you don’t need to mention the `true` and `false` yourself.

```
  }

}
```

---

And here is the whole program again, without all the comments:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Five {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] anArray = new int[5];

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
      anArray[i] = s.nextInt();
    }

    boolean containsThreeAdjacentNumbers = false;
    for (int j = 0; j + 2 < anArray.length; j++) {
      if (anArray[j] + 1 == anArray[j + 1] && anArray[j + 2] == anArray[j + 2]) {
        containsThreeAdjacentNumbers = true;
      }
    }

    System.out.println(containsThreeAdjacentNumbers);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is very simple, and just uses a counter.
Here it is:

```
public boolean tripleUp(int[] nums) {
      //Create a counter starting at 1 for the current character.
      int matchingAmt = 1;
      //Starting, looking at the 2nd character and going onwards, we test to see
      //if the current character is one more than the last.
      for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++)
      {
        //If it is larger by one, we increment matchingAmt;
        if (nums[i] - nums[i-1] == 1)
        {
          matchingAmt++;
        }
        //If it isn't we start back at one.
        else
        {
          matchingAmt = 1;
        }
        //If the matchingAmt is 3, we return true;
        if (matchingAmt == 3)
        {
          return true;
        }
      }
      //Otherwise, if we don't find any groups of 3, we return false.
      return false; 
    }
```